# Ignoring an acronym that is only used once

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package only for its acronym capabilities, and I have one or two that are only used once in the document.  For those acronyms, is there a way to only display the full text?

Specifically, the default is for `\gls{dft}` to display

> density functional theory (DFT),

but I'd like it to only display

> density functional theory

if the acronym is only used once.

Comment: Just for the case that you haven't noticed it: I've added to my answer a patch that extends the `glossaries` package by the special feature you are interested in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get the long form of an acronym—independently of the selected acronym style and the context where the acronym is used—I think it's best to simply use `\acrlong` or `\acl.` Note that the latter command is only defined if the `shortcuts` option of the `glossaries` package is set.

**Edit:** Werner has pointed out in a comment to his answer that it is probably possible to extend the `glossaries` package such that acronyms are printed in a distinct way if they are used only once in the document. The following patch shows that this can indeed be done:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{glossaries}[2011/04/12]

\makeatletter

\appto\newacronymhook{%
  \newbool{glo@\the\glslabeltok @usedonlyonce}% define an additional switch per acronym
}

\patchcmd{\@gls@}{%
  \glsunset{#2}%
}{% write appropriate information to the main auxiliary file
  \ifglsused{#2}{%
    \write\@auxout{\global\setbool{glo@#2@usedonlyonce}{false}}%
  }{%
    \write\@auxout{\global\setbool{glo@#2@usedonlyonce}{true}}%
  }%
  \glsunset{#2}%
}{}{}

\patchcmd{\@gls@}{%
  \glsentryfirst{#2}%
}{% print the long form of the acronym if the acronym is used only once
  \ifbool{glo@#2@usedonlyonce}{\glsentrylong{#2}}{\glsentryfirst{#2}}%
}{}{}

\makeatother

\newacronym{ANO}{ANO}{Acronym Number One}
\newacronym{ANT}{ANT}{Acronym Number Two}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\noindent
\gls{ANO}, \gls{ANO}\\
\gls{ANT}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, you need two LaTeX runs to get everything right. Moreover, if you use not only `\gls` (`\ac`), but also `\Gls` (`\Ac`), `\GLS,` `\glspl` (`\acp`), `\Glspl` (`\Acp`) and `\GLSpl` you have to patch `\@Gls@,` `\@GLS@,` `\@glspl@,` `\@Glspl@` and `\@GLSpl@` in the same way as `\@gls@.`

The resulting output is:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if the need for a double run of LaTeX would be picked up by latexmk?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on how `latexmk` deals with changes in the main auxiliary file (the `mydoc.aux` file).

Comment: I think it monitors if anything changes, and based upon what changes it reruns something appropriate (one hopes).

Comment: I've browsed the documentation of `latexmk`. I think there is a good chance that everything will work out of the box, especially if you are using a current version of `latexmk`.

Comment: OK, I've tested the example in my answer: It works. `latexmk` notices that the main auxiliary file has changed and consequently invokes `latex` a second time.

Comment: short of opening up a bounty, I can't upvote you more than I already have. Otherwise, I'd give another +1.

Comment: i've tried the solution suggested by mhp. However, i#m getting several errors "package etoolbox error: boolean '\ifglo@test@usedonlyonce' undefined"
during the compilation process. does anyone know how to fix this? thanks in advance :)

Comment: @zaungast: Do you use the current version (v3.01) of the `glossaries` package? The patch relies on `\newacronymhook` which isn’t available in older versions.

Comment: This appears to fail if I use glossary entries that are not acronyms: *Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifglo@collocation@usedonlyonce' undefined.* where *collocation* is a glossary entry, but not an acronym.

Comment: @gerrit This is because `\newacronymhook` isn’t evaluated by `\newglossaryentry`.

Comment: @mhp do you have an idea by any chance how one would adapt this to work with `\newglossaryentry?` I tried `\@newglossaryentryprehook` instead of `\newacronymhook` but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: As of patch 4.14 of the Glossaries package, this answer no longer works. A workaround is posted here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98494/glossaries-dont-print-single-occurences/230664#230664

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `first` key for these entries when you declare them via

```
\newacronym[<key-val list>]{<label>}{<abbrv>}{<long>}
```

Even though the `first` key is described under the definition of `\newglossaryentry`, `\newacronym` uses `\newglossaryentry` to define acronyms. Consequently, the following is taken from the [`glossaries` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html):

> #### first
>
> How the entry will appear in the document text on first
>   use with `\gls` (or one of its uppercase variants). If this field is
>   omitted, the value of the `text` key is used. Note that if you use
>   `\glspl`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl`, `\glsdisp` before using `\gls`, the `firstplural`
>   value won’t be used with `\gls`.

So, specifically for your case, you would probably define it this way:

```
\newacronym%
  [first={density functional theory},...]% <key-val list>
  {dft}% <label>
  {DFT}% <abbrv>
  {density functional theory}% <long>
```

The following minimal example illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}% http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries
\begin{document}
\newacronym%
  [first={density functional theory}]% <key-val list>
  {dft}% <label>
  {DFT}% <abbrv>
  {density functional theory}% <long>

Blah blah blah \gls{dft}. Blah blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

[image: First use of an acronym using the glossaries package]

Comment: Definitely useful. But, I'm more looking for something where LaTeX will programmatically determine that I've only used it once, so the acronym need not be included. I'd like to create a glossary file that I can import and not have to manually reset this if I only use something once.

Comment: Such an implementation would require a usage counter (to keep track oh how many times an acronym is called for), require 3 compilations (first to establish all counts; second to rewrite those acronyms only used once; third to possibly adjust references due to the rewrite during the second parse) and be optional to the user via a package choice - since the behaviour may be specific. I would contact the package author and see whether this is possible to include in a future version.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: @Werner I don't think it requires counters. I guess that a line in `.aux` file for every _but the first_ occurence of the acronym would be enough, and a glossary package anyways has to determine whether it is first or other occurence. The next time you go thru the `.aux` file and you don't print the abbr. at the first occurence if the abbr. was not used in the previous run. I think that three runs of `latex` would be sufficient then. *Disclaimer:* I have never used any glossary package so I'm not able to code this myself.

Comment: @tohecz: Sure, if "every *but the first*" is properly defined. Counters just make it easy, since it can be used with "all occurrences" and still yield valuable information.