# "\printglossaries" prints nothing

Tags: texmaker, glossaries

I make a glossaries with the following snippet of code,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{NGI}{NGI}{Next-Generation Internet} \newcommand{\NGI}{\gls{NGI}}
\newacronym{LEO}{LEO}{Low Earth Orbit} \newcommand{\LEO}{\gls{LEO}}
\newacronym{MEO}{MEO}{Medium Earth Orbit} \newcommand{\MEO}{\gls{MEO}}

\begin{document}

Just for test.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

But the output document only contains `Just for test`, not glossaries. I checked with [glossaries: don't print single occurences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98494/glossaries-dont-print-single-occurences) and can't see any problem with my code.

Here is a part of compilation info.

```
$ latex main.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

....

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-
307.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.st
y) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty))
(./main.aux) (./main.glsdefs)
No file main.gls.
[1] (./main.aux) )
Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 232 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.
```

---

As pointed by @NicolaTalbot, there is still nothing after running `makeglossaries main`.

```
$ makeglossaries main
makeglossaries version 2.12 (2014-01-20)
added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
Warning: File 'main.glo' is empty.
Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'main'?
Remember to use package option 'nomain' if you
don't want to use the main glossary.
```

PS: my platform is Ubuntu + Texmaker.

Comment: `No file main.gls` means you either haven't run `makeglossaries` or something went wrong with with the attempt to generate that file. Did you try `makeglossaries main` after `latex main`? If you have run `makeglossaries` try [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313885) for debugging help.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, thx for the quick response. `makeglossaries main` reminds me `File 'main.glo' is empty`. I just added to my answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice earlier, you haven't used any of the entries in the document (there are no commands like `\gls` or `\glsadd`).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, thx again. Would you please give the detailed description as an answer?