# Problems with \glsenableentrycount when \usepackage{glossaries-extra} instead of \usepackage{glossaries}

Tags: glossaries

Recently the package `glossaries-extra` was released to supplement `glossaries`

Among the first couple pages of the documentation is the following example:

> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage{glossaries-extra}
>
> **This is like:**
>
> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage[toc,nopostdot]{glossaries}
>
> \usepackage{glossaries-extra}

But I have noticed that when trying to make use of `\glsenableentrycount` the following two lines are not equivalent.

```
%\usepackage[savewrites=true,nogroupskip,toc,nopostdot]{glossaries} % ====> THIS WORKS FINE
\usepackage[savewrites=true,nogroupskip,acronym]{glossaries-extra}  % ====> THIS DOESN'T WORK BUT I EXPECTED IT TO BE EQUIVALENT
```

Using one of these lines in the MWE below, I have observed that I can't use the `usepackage` call on `glossaries-extra` (with or without `glossaries` as shown the quoted documentation example) and have `\glsenableentrycount` work.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[savewrites=true,nogroupskip,toc,nopostdot]{glossaries} % ====> THIS WORKS FINE
\usepackage[savewrites=true,nogroupskip,acronym]{glossaries-extra}  % ====> THIS DOESN'T WORK

\usepackage{scrwfile}%http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#glsnewwriteexceeded

\ifdefined\HCode    \usepackage{morewrites} \else   \fi

\makeindex % activate index-making
\makeglossaries

\glsenableentrycount % enable \cgls, \cglspl, \cGls, \cGlspl

% UPDATE:  TRY ENABLING ENTRYCOUNT ATTRIBUTE
% http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:entrycountmods
%\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{entrycount}{1} 
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{entrycount}{1} 

%%%%% define synonyms to use counts by default
%%%%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98494/glossaries-dont-print-single-occurences
    \let\gls\cgls
    \let\glspl\cglspl
    \let\Gls\cGls
    \let\Glspl\cGlspl

\glssetnoexpandfield{first}
\glssetnoexpandfield{firstpl}

\newglossaryentry{SRS}{ type={acronym}, sort={stimulated Raman scattering},  name={SRS}, short={SRS}, long={stimulated Raman scattering}, first={stimulated Raman scattering (SRS)}, description={stimulated Raman scattering  } }

\newglossaryentry{CARS}{ type={acronym}, sort={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering},  name={CARS}, short={CARS}, long={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering}, first={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering (CARS)}, description={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering  } }

\glssetexpandfield{first}
\glssetexpandfield{firstpl}

%=============================================================================
%   END GLOSSARY SETUP
%=============================================================================

\begin{document}\noindent\begin{sloppypar}

\gls{CARS} -- I shouldn't see the abbreviation

\cgls{SRS} -- I shouldn't see the abbreviation

\clearpage\end{sloppypar}\end{document}
```

Comment: You also need to [set the entrycount category attribute](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:entrycountmods).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot.  Thanks, I just tried `\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{entrycount}{1} ` and `\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{entrycount}{1} ` but no change.  I will update my question to reflect where I inserted this.

Comment: Okay. I think your comment came while I was answering.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Indeed.  Your answer is very complete, I am sure I will resolve my issue with it.  Although, switching from `\newglossaryentry` to `\newacronym` is not ideal.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Sorry, I don't seem to get the desired output with that.  I have tried the 6 different possible combinations of the three lines `\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{regular}{false}`
`\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{entrycount}{1}` and
`\glsenableentrycount`.  My log file still includes the `Package glossaries-extra Warning: Entry counting has been enabled` that you describe below in your answer.  Is there anything else from my log file I can quote that would be helpful?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was incorrect. You can't just set the `regular` attribute to `false` or `\gls` will assume the abbreviation style associated with that category is required. Have you checked that you have `category=acronym` in your `\newglossaryentry` commands? I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [2.3 Entry Counting Modifications](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:entrycountmods):

> The `\glsenableentrycount` command is modified to allow for the
>   `entrycount` attribute. This means that you not only need to enable
>   entry counting with `\glsenableentrycount`, but you also need to set the
>   appropriate attribute (see [§5 Categories](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:entrycount)).
>
> For example, instead of just doing:
>
> ```
>  \glsenableentrycount
> ```
>
> you now need to do:
>
> ```
>  \glsenableentrycount
>  \glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{entrycount}{1}
> ```
>
> This will enable the entry counting for entries in the `abbreviation`
>   category, but any entries assigned to other categories will be
>   unchanged.

This allows the entry counting to be applied to certain types of entries, and it also allows you to set a different trigger value. There should have been a warning in your transcript file:

```
Package glossaries-extra Warning: Entry counting has been enabled 
(glossaries-extra)                with \glsenableentrycount but the 
(glossaries-extra)                attribute `entrycount' hasn't 
(glossaries-extra)                been assigned to any of the defined 
(glossaries-extra)                entries.
```

This is a reminder that you need to set the `entrycount` attribute.

In your example, you have entry definitions like

```
\newglossaryentry{SRS}{ type={acronym}, sort={stimulated Raman scattering},  name={SRS}, short={SRS}, long={stimulated Raman scattering}, first={stimulated Raman scattering (SRS)}, description={stimulated Raman scattering  } }
```

Since this doesn't explicitly set the category, it defaults to the `general` category, so you'd need to add:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{entrycount}{1}
```

However, this type of explicit definition of an abbreviation using `\newglossaryentry` defeats the purpose of the entry counting, since `first` contains the abbreviation so it will always show (since it's a regular entry, `\cgls` internally uses the value of the `first` key). If you want the abbreviation suppressed with `\cgls`, you need to define the abbreviation using `\newabbreviation` (or `\newacronym`).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[savewrites=true,nogroupskip,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{scrwfile}

\ifdefined\HCode    \usepackage{morewrites} \else   \fi

\makeindex % activate index-making
\makeglossaries

\glsenableentrycount % enable \cgls, \cglspl, \cGls, \cGlspl
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{entrycount}{1}

\let\gls\cgls
\let\glspl\cglspl
\let\Gls\cGls
\let\Glspl\cGlspl

\glssetnoexpandfield{first}
\glssetnoexpandfield{firstpl}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym[sort={stimulated Raman scattering}]
 {SRS}{SRS}{stimulated Raman scattering}

\newacronym[sort={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering}]
 {CARS}{CARS}{coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering}

\glssetexpandfield{first}
\glssetexpandfield{firstpl}

%=============================================================================
%   END GLOSSARY SETUP
%=============================================================================

\begin{document}\noindent\begin{sloppypar}

\gls{CARS} -- I shouldn't see the abbreviation

\cgls{SRS} -- I shouldn't see the abbreviation

\clearpage\end{sloppypar}\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image showing long forms with no abbreviations]

Now suppose I change the `CARS` entry so that it uses `\newabbreviation` instead of `\newacronym`. This sets the category to `abbreviation`, so it's not controlled by the entry counting mechanism (which has only been enabled for the `acronym` category).

```
\newabbreviation[sort={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering}]
 {CARS}{CARS}{coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering}
```

Now this entry includes the abbreviation even though it's only used once:

[image: image of result CARS entry includes abbreviation]

*Edit:* If you really want to use `\newglossaryentry` instead of `\newabbreviation` (or `\newacronym`) then you'll need to redefine `\cglsformat` to just check for the `long` field (and ignore the regular atttibute). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[savewrites=true,nogroupskip,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\glsenableentrycount % enable \cgls, \cglspl, \cGls, \cGlspl
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{entrycount}{1}

\let\gls\cgls
\let\glspl\cglspl
\let\Gls\cGls
\let\Glspl\cGlspl

\glssetnoexpandfield{first}
\glssetnoexpandfield{firstpl}

\newglossaryentry{SRS}{
  type={acronym},
  category={acronym},% <- category
  sort={stimulated Raman scattering},
  name={SRS},
  short={SRS},
  long={stimulated Raman scattering},
  first={stimulated Raman scattering (SRS)},
  description={stimulated Raman scattering}
}

\newglossaryentry{CARS}{
  type={acronym},
  category={acronym},% <- category
  sort={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering},
  name={CARS},
  short={CARS},
  long={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering},
  first={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering (CARS)},
  description={coherent anti-Stokes Raman scattering}
}

\glssetexpandfield{first}
\glssetexpandfield{firstpl}

% Not using \newabbreviation so redefine \cglsformat
% to just check for the long field.
\renewcommand*{\cglsformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#1}{\glsentrylong{#1}}{\glsentryfirst{#1}}#2%
}

\begin{document}\noindent\begin{sloppypar}

\gls{CARS} -- I shouldn't see the abbreviation

\cgls{SRS} -- I shouldn't see the abbreviation

\clearpage\end{sloppypar}\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of result with no abbreviations]

If you're still getting the above warning, first check that the `category` has been correctly set for your entries. For example, if you add:

```
Category of CARS: \glscategory{CARS}.
Category of SRS: \glscategory{SRS}.
```

to your document, the PDF should show

[image: Category of CARS: acronym. Category of SRS: acronym.]

If it doesn't, then check the `category` element in `\newglossaryentry`.

Next check that the `entrycount` attribute has been correctly set. You can do this by adding the following to your document:

```
entrycount attribute for CARS: \glsgetattribute{CARS}{entrycount}.
entrycount attribute for SRS: \glsgetattribute{SRS}{entrycount}.
```

This should show

[image: entrycount attribute for CARS: 1. entrycount attribute for SRS: 1.]

If it doesn't check the spelling of the category label and the attribute label in

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{entrycount}{1}
```

If you need to use the plural or case-changing versions, you similarly need to redefine the analogous commands. The first letter uppercase command `\cGls` uses `\cGlsformat`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cGlsformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#1}{\Glsentrylong{#1}}{\Glsentryfirst{#1}}#2%
}
```

(Make sure you have at least v1.14 of `glossaries-extra` that fixes the bug with `\cGls`.)

The all capitals version `\cGLS` uses `\cGLSformat`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cGLSformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#1}%
  {\MakeUppercase{\glsentrylong{#1}}}
  {\MakeUppercase{\glsentryfirst{#1}}}\MakeUppercase{#2}%
}
```

(or you may prefer to use `\mfirstucMakeUppercase` to be consistent with `\GLS`.)

If you need to use the plural forms, remember that the `long`, `short`, `longplural` and `shortplural` keys were actually provided for `\newacronym` and `\newabbreviation` and require explicit setting if used directly in `\newglossaryentry`. This means that if you're not using the abbreviation interface but are explicitly uses `\newglossaryentry` (as in the above example), then `longplural` and `shortplural` must be explicitly set if required, otherwise they will be empty.

There isn't a plural equivalent to `\ifglshaslong`, although you can use `\ifglshasfield` instead. There are several ways of redefining `\cglsplformat`. The simplistic approach is:

```
\renewcommand*{\cglsplformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#1}{\glsentrylongpl{#1}}{\glsentryfirstpl{#1}}#2%
}
```

This just checks if the `long` field has been set. In the above example, the `long` field has been set (so `\ifglshaslong` is true) but `longplural` hasn't been set, which means that `\glsentrylongpl` will expand to nothing for the entries in the above example. It really depends on what you want to happen in this situation. You could instead check for `longplural`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cglsplformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshasfield{longplural}{#1}{\glsentrylongpl{#1}}{\glsentryfirstpl{#1}}#2%
}
```

or you might want to default to the `long` field if `long` has been set but `longplural` hasn't:

```
\renewcommand*{\cglsplformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#1}%
  {\ifglshasfield{longplural}{#1}{\glsentrylongpl{#1}}{\glsentrylong{#1}}}%
  {\glsentryfirstpl{#1}}#2%
}
```

Similarly for `\cGlsplformat` and `\cGLSplformat`.

Comment: This has been a really helpful answer that I keep coming back to.  I've just noticed however that in the MWE of the edit that if I use`\Gls` instead of `\gls{}`, it stops working (I get the abbreviation).  I've played around with trying to create a capital instance with`\cGlsformat` (as suggested http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98494/glossaries-dont-print-single-occurences) but I haven't any observable changes so my guess that the capital pattern matching may not be correct.  Which format command should I try editing to get the count working on the redefined `\Gls{}`?

Comment: @EngBIRD There's a bug in `glossaries-extra`'s version of `\glsenableentrycount`. I'll get it fixed.