# Glossaries entry counting on a new field conflicts with printglossaries on type

Tags: glossaries

So I'm not sure why I didn't have this problem using a list based glossary style, but when I enable glossary counting on a specific subset of terms in the acronym type (i.e. a new field called category) there appears to be some confusion in what term usage results in unsetting of the term so that it is included in the list.  In simple examples there's no problem with first and short expansions but they aren't printed in the list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textgreek}

    \usepackage[savewrites=true,nogroupskip,style=tree]{glossaries-extra}

    \newcommand{\acrinverse}[1]{{\acrshort{#1}}\xspace{\acrlong{#1}}}

    \newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{List of Acronyms}

\makeindex
\makeglossaries

    \glsenableentrycount % enable \cgls, \cglspl, \cGls, \cGlspl
    \glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{entrycount}{1}

    % Not using \newabbreviation so redefine \cglsformat
    % to just check for the long field.
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319997/problems-with-glsenableentrycount-when-usepackageglossaries-extra-instead-of
    \renewcommand*{\cglsformat}[2]{%
        \ifglshaslong{#1}{\glsentrylong{#1}}{\glsentryfirst{#1}}#2%
    }

\AtEndPreamble{%
    \let\ncgls\gls
    \let\ncglspl\glspl
    \let\ncGls\Gls
    \let\ncGlspl\Glspl

    \let\gls\cgls
    \let\glspl\cglspl
    \let\Gls\cGls
    \let\Glspl\cGlspl
}
%==================================================================================================================================================================

\newglossarystyle{paragraphAcronymList}{%
    \setglossarystyle{tree}% base this style on the list style
    \def\entrysep{\def\entrysep{; }}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}}%
    {.}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \entrysep\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}:~\space\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription}%
}

%==================================================================================================================================================================

\newglossaryentry{TNF}{ 
    type={acronym}, 
    category={acronym},
    sort={tumor necrosis factor},  
    name={TNF}, 
    first={tumor necrosis factor (TNF)}, 
    description={tumor necrosis factor}
}   

\glssetnoexpandfield{first}
\glssetnoexpandfield{firstpl}

\newcommand{\TNFalpha}{TNF--{\textalpha}}

\newglossaryentry{TNFalpha}{
    type={acronym},
    category={acronym},
    sort={tumor necrosis factor alpha},
    name={\TNFalpha}, 
    first={\ifglsused{TNF}{\TNFalpha}{\glsunset{TNF}tumor necrosis factor alpha~(\TNFalpha)}},
    description={tumor necrosis factor alpha}
}
\newglossaryentry{HDPE}
{ 
    type={acronym},  
    category={acronym},
    name={HDPE}, 
    short={HDPE}, 
    long={high density polyethylene}, 
    first={high density polyethylene (HDPE)}, 
    description={high density polyethylene}
}

\newglossaryentry{SHG}{%
    type={acronym},
    category={acronym},
    name={SHG},
    short={SHG},
    long={second harmonic generation},
    description={second harmonic generation},
    first={second harmonic generation (SHG)},
    sort={second harmonic generation}
}%

\newglossaryentry{SRS}{%
    type={acronym},
    category={acronym},
    name={SRS},
    short={SRS},
    long={stimulated Raman scattering},
    description={stimulated Raman scattering},
    first={stimulated Raman scattering (SRS)},
    sort={stimulated Raman scattering}
}%

\newglossaryentry{TPEF}{%
    type={acronym},
    category={acronym},
    name={TPEF},
    short={TPEF},
    long={two-photon-excited fluorescence},
    description={two-photon-excited fluorescence},
    first={two-photon-excited fluorescence (TPEF) },
    sort={two-photon-excited fluorescence}
}%


\begin{document}

    \gls{TNFalpha}  
    \gls{TNFalpha}

    \gls{TNF}
    \gls{TNF}

     \gls{HDPE} 
     \gls{HDPE} 

     \gls{TPEF}
     \gls{TPEF} 

     \gls{SHG}   
     \gls{SHG} 

     \gls{SRS} 
     \gls{SRS}

    \printglossary[type=acronym,style=paragraphAcronymList]\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your build process? With the entry counting enabled, two LaTeX runs are required before `makeglossaries` to determine which entries should be included. Your MWE works fine for me with `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`, `makeglossaries`, `pdflatex` and produces:

[image: image of document]

All referenced entries are listed in the glossary.

Incidentally, there are some differences between the way `glossaries` and `glossaries-extra` handle entry counting. With `glossaries-extra`'s `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting`, you can use `\gls` etc directly, so you don't need the code in your `\AtEndPreamble`. If the term being referenced has had entry counting enabled for its category then this will automatically use `\cgls` otherwise it will use the original `\gls`.

You can take advantage of the more sophisticated abbreviation handling provided by `glossaries-extra` to deal with your `TNFalpha` entry. You can define an abbreviation style for abbreviations that are dependent on another term. For example, if the dependent abbreviation uses the `user1` key to store the label of the term it's dependent on, then the following style definition can be used:

```
\newabbreviationstyle{dependent}%
{% base it on the long-short style
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleSetup{long-short}%
}
{% base it on long-short
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
% full form no case-changing format:
  \renewcommand*{\glsxtrfullformat}[2]{%
    % get the dependent label
    \glsfieldfetch{##1}{useri}{\deplabel}%
    % if the dependent term has been used, just use this term's name
    \ifglsused{\deplabel}{\glsentrytext{##1}}%
    {% otherwise, unset dependent term and do long form followed by
     % short form
      \glsunset{\deplabel}\glsentrylong{##1}~(\glsentryshort{##1})%
    }%
  }%
% full plural form no case-changing format:
  \renewcommand*{\glsxtrfullplformat}[2]{%
    % get the dependent label
    \glsfieldfetch{##1}{useri}{\deplabel}%
    % if the dependent term has been used, just use this term's name
    \ifglsused{\deplabel}{\glsentryplural{##1}}%
    {% otherwise, unset dependent term and do long form followed by
     % short form
      \glsunset{\deplabel}\glsentrylongpl{##1}~(\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
    }%
  }%
% full form first letter upper case format:
  \renewcommand*{\Glsxtrfullformat}[2]{%
    % get the dependent label
    \glsfieldfetch{##1}{useri}{\deplabel}%
    % if the dependent term has been used, just use this term's name
    \ifglsused{\deplabel}{\Glsentrytext{##1}}%
    {% otherwise, unset dependent term and do long form followed by
     % short form
      \glsunset{\deplabel}\Glsentrylong{##1}~(\glsentryshort{##1})%
    }%
  }%
% full plural form first letter upper case format:
  \renewcommand*{\glsxtrfullplformat}[2]{%
    % get the dependent label
    \glsfieldfetch{##1}{useri}{\deplabel}%
    % if the dependent term has been used, just use this term's name
    \ifglsused{\deplabel}{\Glsentryplural{##1}}%
    {% otherwise, unset dependent term and do long form followed by
     % short form
      \glsunset{\deplabel}\Glsentrylongpl{##1}~(\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
    }%
  }%
}
```

The `TNFalpha` term can then be given the category label `dependent` with the above `dependent` style:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[dependent]{dependent}

\newacronym[sort={TNF-a},category=dependent,user1=TNF]% dependent on TNF
 {TNFalpha}{TNF--{\textalpha}}{tumor necrosis factor alpha}
```

This has the advantage in that it won't break if you happen to start a sentence with `\Gls{TNFalpha}`. The code at the start of your `first` key will break with this. The following works fine. (The build sequence is `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`, `makeglossaries`, `pdflatex`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{abbreviation,dependent}{1}

\newglossarystyle{paragraphAcronymList}{%
    \setglossarystyle{tree}% base this style on the list style
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
    \def\entrysep{\def\entrysep{; }}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}}%
    {.}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \entrysep\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}:~\space\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription}%
}

% style for abbreviations dependent on another abbreviation
% (the dependent term should be supplied in the user1 key)

\newabbreviationstyle{dependent}%
{% base it on the long-short style
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleSetup{long-short}%
}
{% base it on long-short
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{long-short}%
% full form no case-changing format:
  \renewcommand*{\glsxtrfullformat}[2]{%
    % get the dependent label
    \glsfieldfetch{##1}{useri}{\deplabel}%
    % if the dependent term has been used, just use this term's name
    \ifglsused{\deplabel}{\glsentrytext{##1}}%
    {% otherwise, unset dependent term and do long form followed by
     % short form
      \glsunset{\deplabel}\glsentrylong{##1}~(\glsentryshort{##1})%
    }%
  }%
% full plural form no case-changing format:
  \renewcommand*{\glsxtrfullplformat}[2]{%
    % get the dependent label
    \glsfieldfetch{##1}{useri}{\deplabel}%
    % if the dependent term has been used, just use this term's name
    \ifglsused{\deplabel}{\glsentryplural{##1}}%
    {% otherwise, unset dependent term and do long form followed by
     % short form
      \glsunset{\deplabel}\glsentrylongpl{##1}~(\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
    }%
  }%
% full form first letter upper case format:
  \renewcommand*{\Glsxtrfullformat}[2]{%
    % get the dependent label
    \glsfieldfetch{##1}{useri}{\deplabel}%
    % if the dependent term has been used, just use this term's name
    \ifglsused{\deplabel}{\Glsentrytext{##1}}%
    {% otherwise, unset dependent term and do long form followed by
     % short form
      \glsunset{\deplabel}\Glsentrylong{##1}~(\glsentryshort{##1})%
    }%
  }%
% full plural form first letter upper case format:
  \renewcommand*{\glsxtrfullplformat}[2]{%
    % get the dependent label
    \glsfieldfetch{##1}{useri}{\deplabel}%
    % if the dependent term has been used, just use this term's name
    \ifglsused{\deplabel}{\Glsentryplural{##1}}%
    {% otherwise, unset dependent term and do long form followed by
     % short form
      \glsunset{\deplabel}\Glsentrylongpl{##1}~(\glsentryshortpl{##1})%
    }%
  }%
}

\setabbreviationstyle[abbreviation]{long-short}
\setabbreviationstyle[dependent]{dependent}

\newabbreviation{HDPE}{HDPE}{high density polyethylene}
\newabbreviation{TNF}{TNF}{tumor necrosis factor}
\newabbreviation{SHG}{SHG}{second harmonic generation}
\newabbreviation{SRS}{SRS}{stimulated Raman scattering}
\newabbreviation{TPEF}{TPEF}{two-photon-excited fluorescence}

\newabbreviation[sort={TNF-a},category=dependent,user1=TNF]% dependent on TNF
 {TNFalpha}{TNF--{\textalpha}}{tumor necrosis factor alpha}


\begin{document}

\gls{TNFalpha}  
\gls{TNFalpha}

\gls{TNF}
\gls{TNF}

\gls{HDPE} 
\gls{HDPE} 

\gls{TPEF}
\gls{TPEF} 

\gls{SHG}   
\gls{SHG} 

\gls{SRS} 
\gls{SRS}


\printabbreviations[title={List of Acronyms},style=paragraphAcronymList]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Now test with the order switched:

```
\gls{TNF}
\gls{TNF}

\gls{TNFalpha}
\gls{TNFalpha}
```

[image: image of document]

Now test the entry counting by removing the second use of `HDPE`:

[image: image of document]

### Internal Workings

Here's a bit more information about the internal working of `\cgls` within `glossaries-extra.sty`.

The actual `\cgls` is simply defined as

```
\@gls@hyp@opt\@cgls
```

This is the original `glossaries` definition that processes the optional modifier (`*` or `+`) and arguments. The `\gls` command is defined in a similar way:

```
\@gls@hyp@opt\@gls
```

The actual inner working is performed by `\@cgls@` (for `\cgls`) and `\@gls@` (for `\gls`). The outer `\@cgls`, `\cgls`, `\@gls` and `\gls` simply provide the convenient user interface.

It's the inner `\@cgls@` command that's redefined by `glossaries-extra`. By default with `glossaries.sty` this internal command generates an error until it's redefined when entry counting is enabled. With `glossaries-extra.sty`, `\@cgls@` is initially redefined to just `\@gls@`. This is why with `glossaries-extra`, `\cgls` by default behaves exactly the same as `\gls`.

When `glossaries-extra`'s `\glsenableentrycount` is used (which is used internally by `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting`) `\@cgls@` is set to `\@@cgls@`. This is defined as follows:

```
\def\@@cgls@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsxtrifcounttrigger{#2}%
  {%
    \cglsformat{#2}{#3}%
    \glsunset{#2}%
  }% 
  {%
    \@gls@{#1}{#2}[#3]%
  }%
}%
```

This uses `\glsxtrifcounttrigger{`*label*`}` to determine whether or not the entry counting applies to *label*. If it doesn't apply, then `\@gls@` is again used, so `\cgls` still behaves in exactly the same way as `\gls` in this instance. If the entry counting is triggered, then the entry is formatted according to `\cglsformat` and is then unset (`\glsunset` increments the total count for that entry in addition to unsetting the first use flag).

For convenience `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting` does

```
\let\gls\cgls
```

so you don't have to modify your document if you decide to add entry counting at some later date. Now instead of directly using `\@gls@`, `\gls` internally uses `\@cgls@` which will only use `\@gls@` if the entry counting mechanism isn't triggered.

The trigger command is defined as:

```
 \newcommand*{\glsxtrifcounttrigger}[3]{%
 \glshasattribute{#1}{entrycount}%
 {%
   \ifnum\glsentryprevcount{#1}>\glsgetattribute{#1}{entrycount}\relax
    #3%
   \else
    #2%
   \fi
 }%
 {#3}% 
}
```

So the first thing it does is check if the `entrycount` attribute has been set for the entry whose label is provided in the first argument. If that attribute hasn't been set then it performs `#3` which will be `\@gls@{`*options*`}{`*label*`}[`*insert*`]` (the normal behaviour of the original `\gls[`*options*`]{`*label*`}[`*insert*`]`).

If the `entrycount` attribute has been set, then it's expected to be an integer. The total count *from the previous run* (`\glsentryprevcount{#1}`) for this entry is then compared against the value of this attribute (`\glsgetattribute{#1}{entrycount}`). That's the only way to find out the total number of times this entry has been used throughout the document. TeX can't look ahead to find out if that entry has been used later. This is why two LaTeX calls are required before `makeglossaries`.

Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{foo,bar}{1}

\newglossaryentry{foo1}{name={foo1},
 category=foo,
 first={foo1 (first use)},
 description={foo 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{foo2}{name={foo2},
 category=foo,
 first={foo2 (first use)},
 description={foo 2 example}}

\newglossaryentry{bar1}{name={bar1},
 category=bar,
 first={bar1 (first use)},
 description={bar 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{bar2}{name={bar2},
 category=bar,
 first={bar2 (first use)},
 description={bar 2 example}}

\newglossaryentry{example1}{name={example1},
 % no category label provided, implicit category=general
 first={example 1 (first use)},
 description={general 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{example2}{name={example2},
 % no category label provided, implicit category=general
 first={example 2 (first use)},
 description={general 2 example}}

\begin{document}
First use.

\gls{foo1}, \gls{foo2}.

\gls{bar1}, \gls{bar2}.

\gls{example1}, \gls{example2}.

Second use.

\gls{foo1}.

\gls{bar1}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

My first call of `pdflatex` adds the following lines to the `.aux` file:

```
\@gls@entry@count{foo1}{2}
\@gls@entry@count{foo2}{1}
\@gls@entry@count{bar1}{2}
\@gls@entry@count{bar2}{1}
```

These are the total number of times `foo1`, `foo2`, `bar1` and `bar2` were used in the document. The entries `example1` and `example2` aren't included because their category (`general`) doesn't have the `entrycount` attribute set.

On this first run `\glsentryprevcount` returns 0 for all entries because there's no previous total count. So the `\ifnum` part in `\glsxtrifcounttrigger` is comparing `0>1`, which is false so this triggers the `\cglsformat` part. This means that the `first` field is always used, even though `foo1` and `bar1` have actually been used twice.

The main body of the document looks like this:

[image: image of document (text shown in quote below)]

> First use.
>  foo1 (first use), foo2 (first use).
>  bar1 (first
>   use), bar2 (first use).
>  example 1 (first use), example 2 (first
>   use).
>  Second use.
>  foo1 (first use).
>  bar1 (first use).

The next `pdflatex` call now has the correct values for `\glsentryprevcount` because they've been supplied in the `.aux` file. The document now looks like:

[image: image of document (text shown in quote below)]

> First use.
>  foo1 (first use), foo2 (first use).
>  bar1 (first
>   use), bar2 (first use).
>  example 1 (first use), example 2 (first
>   use).
>  Second use.
>  foo1.
>  bar1.

In the case of `foo1` and `bar1`, the total entry count from the previous run is 2, so the `\ifnum` conditional is testing `2>1`, which is true so it uses the regular `\@gls@` which means it behaves like a normal `\gls`.

In the case of `foo2` and `bar2`, the total entry count from the previous run is 1, so the test is now `1>1`, which is false, so `\cglsformat` is used instead.

The `glossaries-extra` definition of `\cglsformat` is:

```
\renewcommand*{\cglsformat}[2]{%
  \glsifregular{#1}
  {\glsentryfirst{#1}}%
  {\ifglshaslong{#1}{\glsentrylong{#1}}{\glsentryfirst{#1}}}#2%
}
```

This first checks if the entry is considered "regular". This is determined by the existence and value of the `regular` attribute. If the `regular` attribute is set to `true` (or hasn't been set) for the entry's category it's assumed regular.

Entries defined using `\newglossaryentry` are assumed to be regular by default. Some of the abbreviation styles (such as `long-short`) set the `regular` attribute to `false`. This identifies them as abbreviations that require different treatment to regular entries when being displayed by commands like `\gls`.

In this example, all the entries are regular so `\glsentryfirst` is used. If you want some other field to be used, you can redefine `\cglsformat`. For example, suppose `foo2` is now defined as:

```
\newglossaryentry{foo2}{name={foo2},
 category=foo,
 first={foo2 (first use)},
 long={foooooo2},
 description={foo 2 example}}
```

I can redefine `\cglsformat` to skip the check for the `regular` attribute and check instead for the `long` field:

```
\renewcommand*{\cglsformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshaslong{#1}{\glsentrylong{#1}}{\glsentryfirst{#1}}#2%
}
```

I now get

[image: image of document (text shown in quote below)]

> First use.
>  foo1 (first use), foooooo2.
>  bar1 (first use), bar2
>   (first use).
>  example 1 (first use), example 2 (first use).
>   Second use.
>  foo1.
>  bar1.

Alternatively, another field could be used specifically for this value. For example:

```
\glsaddstoragekey{cformat}{}{\cformatentry}

\renewcommand*{\cglsformat}[2]{%
  \ifglshasfield{cformat}{#1}%
  {\cformatentry{#1}}%
  {%
    \glsifregular{#1}
    {\glsentryfirst{#1}}%
    {\ifglshaslong{#1}{\glsentrylong{#1}}{\glsentryfirst{#1}}}%
  }%
  #2%
}
```

The entry can now be defined as:

```
\newglossaryentry{foo2}{name={foo2},
 category=foo,
 cformat={foooooo2},
 first={foo2 (first use)},
 description={foo 2 example}}
```

If you want different trigger values for different categories, you can change the `entrycount` attribute for the appropriate category like this:

```
\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{foo,bar}{1}
\glssetcategoryattribute{bar}{entrycount}{2}
```

`\cglsformat` is just for the singular no case-changing version (`\gls`). There are analogous commands `\cglsplformat` (plural no case-change), `\cGlsformat` (singular first letter upper case) and `\cGlsplformat` (plural first letter upper case).

Here's an example that uses just the `description` or `descriptionplural` fields regardless of whether or not the entry is considered regular:

```
\renewcommand*{\cglsformat}[2]{%
  \glsentrydesc{#1}#2%
}

\renewcommand*{\cglsplformat}[2]{%
  \glsentrydescplural{#1}#2%
}

\renewcommand*{\cGlsformat}[2]{%
  \Glsentrydesc{#1}#2%
}

\renewcommand*{\cGlsplformat}[2]{%
  \Glsentrydescplural{#1}#2%
}
```

### Resetting the First Use Flag

Note that the entry counting mechanism works by hooking into the macros that modify the first use flag (which is why entry counting is only designed to work with commands that modify the first use flag). This means that `\glsreset` (and therefore `\glsresetall`) not only resets the first use flag but also resets the entry counter. This can be illustrated in the following modification to the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{foo,bar}{1}

\newglossaryentry{foo1}{name={foo1},
 category=foo,
 first={foo1 (first use)},
 description={foo 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{foo2}{name={foo2},
 category=foo,
 first={foo2 (first use)},
 description={foo 2 example}}

\newglossaryentry{bar1}{name={bar1},
 category=bar,
 first={bar1 (first use)},
 description={bar 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{bar2}{name={bar2},
 category=bar,
 first={bar2 (first use)},
 description={bar 2 example}}

\newglossaryentry{example1}{name={example1},
 % no category label provided, implicit category=general
 first={example 1 (first use)},
 description={general 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{example2}{name={example2},
 % no category label provided, implicit category=general
 first={example 2 (first use)},
 description={general 2 example}}

\begin{document}
First use.

\gls{foo1}, \gls{foo2}.

\gls{bar1}, \gls{bar2}.

\gls{example1}, \gls{example2}.

Second use.

\gls{foo1}.

\gls{bar1}.

Current count value. foo1: \glsentrycurrcount{foo1}, 
foo2: \glsentrycurrcount{foo2}, bar1: \glsentrycurrcount{bar1},
bar2: \glsentrycurrcount{bar2}.

Resetting the first use flag resets the counter.\glsresetall

Back to first use.

\gls{foo1}, \gls{foo2}.

\gls{bar1}, \gls{bar2}.

\gls{example1}, \gls{example2}.

Current count value. foo1: \glsentrycurrcount{foo1}, 
foo2: \glsentrycurrcount{foo2}, bar1: \glsentrycurrcount{bar1},
bar2: \glsentrycurrcount{bar2}.

Count value obtained from previous run. foo1: \glsentryprevcount{foo1}, 
foo2: \glsentryprevcount{foo2}, bar1: \glsentryprevcount{bar1},
bar2: \glsentryprevcount{bar2}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document, text reproduced below]

> First use.
>   foo1 (first use), foo2 (first use).
>   bar1 (first use), bar2 (first use).
>   example 1 (first use), example 2 (first use).
>   Second use.
>   foo1 (first use).
>   bar1 (first use).
>   Current count value. foo1: 2, foo2: 1, bar1: 2, bar2: 1.
>   Resetting the first use flag resets the counter.
>   Back to first use.
>   foo1 (first use), foo2 (first use).
>   bar1 (first use), bar2 (first use).
>   example 1 (first use), example 2 (first use).
>   Current count value. foo1: 1, foo2: 1, bar1: 1, bar2: 1.
>   Count value obtained from previous run. foo1: 1, foo2: 1, bar1: 1, bar2: 1.
>
> **Glossary**
>   **example1** general 1 example 1
>   **example2** general 2 example 1

The current count value is obtained through `\glsentrycurrcount`. This is incremented at every `\glsunset` and reset to zero at every `\glsreset`. At the end of the document the value is written to the `.aux` file and can be retrieved on the next run with `\glsentryprevcount`.

It's therefore not advisable to use `\glsreset` (or `\glsresetall`) when using the document-wide entry counting mechanism. If you are resetting per sectional unit, then it's better to use the unit-counting version. For example, the above document is converted so that the unit counting is per `\section`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting{foo,bar}{1}{section}

\newglossaryentry{foo1}{name={foo1},
 category=foo,
 first={foo1 (first use)},
 description={foo 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{foo2}{name={foo2},
 category=foo,
 first={foo2 (first use)},
 description={foo 2 example}}

\newglossaryentry{bar1}{name={bar1},
 category=bar,
 first={bar1 (first use)},
 description={bar 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{bar2}{name={bar2},
 category=bar,
 first={bar2 (first use)},
 description={bar 2 example}}

\newglossaryentry{example1}{name={example1},
 % no category label provided, implicit category=general
 first={example 1 (first use)},
 description={general 1 example}}

\newglossaryentry{example2}{name={example2},
 % no category label provided, implicit category=general
 first={example 2 (first use)},
 description={general 2 example}}

\begin{document}
\section{Sample Section}
First use.

\gls{foo1}, \gls{foo2}.

\gls{bar1}, \gls{bar2}.

\gls{example1}, \gls{example2}.

Second use.

\gls{foo1}.

\gls{bar1}.

Current count value. foo1: \glsentrycurrcount{foo1}, 
foo2: \glsentrycurrcount{foo2}, bar1: \glsentrycurrcount{bar1},
bar2: \glsentrycurrcount{bar2}.

\section{Another Section}
Resetting the first use flag.\glsresetall

Back to first use.

\gls{foo1}, \gls{foo2}.

\gls{bar1}, \gls{bar2}.

\gls{example1}, \gls{example2}.

Current count value. foo1: \glsentrycurrcount{foo1}, 
foo2: \glsentrycurrcount{foo2}, bar1: \glsentrycurrcount{bar1},
bar2: \glsentrycurrcount{bar2}.

Count value obtained from previous run for the current section.
foo1: \glsentryprevcount{foo1}, 
foo2: \glsentryprevcount{foo2}, bar1: \glsentryprevcount{bar1},
bar2: \glsentryprevcount{bar2}.

Total count value obtained from previous run for the entire document.
foo1: \glsentryprevtotalcount{foo1}, 
foo2: \glsentryprevtotalcount{foo2}, bar1: \glsentryprevtotalcount{bar1},
bar2: \glsentryprevtotalcount{bar2}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This now produces:

[image: image of document, text reproduced below]

> **1 Sample Section**
>   First use.
>   foo1 (first use), foo2 (first use).
>   bar1 (first use), bar2 (first use).
>   example 1 (first use), example 2 (first use).
>   Second use.
>   foo1.
>   bar1.
>   Current count value. foo1: 2, foo2: 1, bar1: 2, bar2: 1.
>
> **2 Another Section**
>   Resetting the first use flag.
>   Back to first use.
>   foo1 (first use), foo2 (first use).
>   bar1 (first use), bar2 (first use).
>   example 1 (first use), example 2 (first use).
>   Current count value. foo1: 1, foo2: 1, bar1: 1, bar2: 1.
>   Count value obtained from previous run for the current section. foo1: 1, foo2: 1, bar1: 1, bar2: 1.
>   Total count value obtained from previous run for the entire document. foo1:
>   3, foo2: 2, bar1: 3, bar2: 2.
>
> **Glossary**
>   **bar1** bar 1 example 1
>   **example1** general 1 example 1
>   **example2** general 2 example 1
>   **foo1** foo 1 example 1

Comment: I don't yet have a MWE prepared to update my question with, but I'm having trouble understanding how the `\renewcommand*{\gls}{\cgls}%` type of redefinition performed by `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting` manages to stay specific to the type of value in the declaring list.  When I define a new glossary type, i.e. supplier, or product, I find that it stops working when I only have one instance. I want to see companies expanded even if only used once because it has to show the info at least once.  To me, the logic of using a minimum instance count of 0 would do it, but this doesn't work it.

Comment: @EngBIRD I've added more detail to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for all this great information! It really helps to understand what's going on specific to how it's being used. It helps put the manual in context. I think the problem in my second question is a problem more likely linked to nested glossary terms in my declarations i.e. a custom glossary type called products, referencing another custom glossary type called supplier with a first use `Catalogue No. 6210H; \ncgls{corp_Cambridge}`. It used to work, but I have so many complex commands,`glssetnoexpandfield` etc, that I'm sure I'm mashing up some expansions because it used to expand.

Comment: @EngBIRD It might be better to use a command like `\glspt` instead (described in [Nested Links](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested)). There are also some debugging commands listed in section 1.20 of the [`glossaries` documented code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-code.pdf) that you can use to test how values have been expanded. For example, `\showglofirst{TNFalpha}` will show the actual value of the `first` field for the `TNFalpha` entry.

Comment: Is there a `user1` equivalant in `newglossaryentry`.  At this stage, my infastructure has me committed to `newglossaryentry` and I'm not sure how easy it would be to switch to `newacronym`.  I think I'm slowly making progress on this.  Sorry this question has stayed open so long.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EngBIRD You can use `user1` in `\newglossaryentry`. All the key=value options in the optional argument of `\newacronym` are internally passed to the second argument of `\newglossaryentry`, so any key that you can use in one you can also use in the other.

Comment: Hi again, Sorry it's been a while, but I finally figured out what's confusing me about my expectations in the second half of your post (`Here's a simple example`) and outputs matched by `\newabbreviation` and solutions with like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230664/69378 with `\newacronym`.`\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{category}{n}` repeats first use `n` times.  I've been expecting it to use 'description' or 'descriptionplural', i.e. no need to give an acronym because it's never used more than once. Using your second simple example commenting out everything after second use leaves me with (xx).

Comment: More specifically it repeats `\cglsformat` `n` times. If you want it to use `description` or `descriptionplural`, you need to redefine `\cglsformat` to use `\glsentrydesc` instead (and `\cglsplformat` to use `\glsentrydescplural`).

Comment: Hi again.  I'm still trying to characterize the behavior I'm generating, but I think I'm breaking `GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting` when trying to use one of the `...resetlocalall...` or `...resetall...` commands.  I.e. the document breaks down and always uses the first use instance.  And If I'm using the `cglsformat` defined above, I only get the description entry.  Is there an environment I can define to truly have a proper localized/contained scope of the document?  To reproduce this as an MWE, repeating the body text below a `\glsresetall` command should break the counting.  Thanks!

Comment: @EngBIRD I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm still generating a little glitch.  If from your last MWE I comment out `\glsresetall` I get exactly what I want -- but this MWE is unique, in the second section there are no multi-use cases of acronyms.  So if I modify the second section to include a second instance, it forgets to redisplay the first use use (or n use because its got counting enabled) expansion.  i.e. `Back to first use. \gls{foo1}, \gls{foo1}.` shows "foo1, foo1" as opposed to "foo1 (first use), foo1".  Thanks again!

Comment: @EngBIRD If you remove `\glsresetall` then `\gls{foo1}` in the second section is no longer the first use so it will just show "foo1" rather that "foo1 (first use)". I think it might be easier to post a follow-up question to clarify the problem.