# Glossaries: introduce short name only if used more than once within section/chapter/part

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to obtain the following behavior: If an acronym is only used once within a section/chapter/part, at this occurrence only the long name should be used. If however the acronym is used more than one, I want the `long-short` behavior.

I have the following non working MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpcompare}{ m m m }
{
    % #1 = test to perform
    % #2 = text for the true case
    % #3 = text for the false case
    \fp_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[acronym,symbols,nomain,toc,sanitizesort,nogroupskip,xindy,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries-extra}
\setglossarystyle{super}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting{acronym}{1}{section}
%\renewcommand*{\gls}{\cgls}%
%\renewcommand*{\Gls}{\cGls}%
%\renewcommand*{\glspl}{\cglspl}%
%\renewcommand*{\Glspl}{\cGlspl}%
%\renewcommand*{\GLS}{\cGLS}%
%\renewcommand*{\GLSpl}{\cGLSpl}%


\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{wn}{WN}{wireless network}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={pi},type=symbols]{symb:pi}{\ensuremath{\pi}}%


\usepackage{xstring}
\renewcommand*{\gls}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\glscategory{#1}}{acronym}{%to apply this to acronym only (and not symbols as well)
        \fpcompare{\glsentrycurrcount{#1} > 1}{\glsentrydesc{#1}}{\cgls{#1}}% fpcompare to detect how often used 
    }{%
        \cgls{#1}%
    }%
}%
\renewcommand*{\Gls}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\glscategory{#1}}{acronym}{%
        \fpcompare{\glsentrycurrcount{#1} > 1}{\Glsentrydesc{#1}}{\cgls{#1}}%
    }{%
        \cgls{#1}%
    }%
}%
\renewcommand*{\glspl}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\glscategory{#1}}{acronym}{%
        \fpcompare{\glsentrycurrcount{#1} > 1}{\glsentryplural{#1}}{\cglspl{#1}}%
    }{%
        \cglspl{#1}%
    }%
}%
\renewcommand*{\Glspl}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\glscategory{#1}}{acronym}{%
        \fpcompare{\glsentrycurrcount{#1} > 1}{\Glsentryplural{#1}}{\cglspl{#1}}%
    }{%
        \cglspl{#1}%
    }%
}%
\renewcommand*{\GLS}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\glscategory{#1}}{acronym}{%
        \fpcompare{\glsentrycurrcount{#1} > 1}{\GLSentrydesc{#1}}{\cgls{#1}}%
    }{%
        \cgls{#1}%
    }%
}%
\renewcommand*{\GLSpl}[1]{%
    \IfEq{\glscategory{#1}}{acronym}{%
        \fpcompare{\glsentrycurrcount{#1} > 1}{\GLSentryplural{#1}}{\cglspl{#1}}%
    }{%
        \cglspl{#1}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \gls{wn}\\
    \glspl{wn}\\
    \glspl{wn}\\
    \glspl{wn}\\
    count: \glsentrycurrcount{wn}\\
    \gls{symb:pi}
    \section{B} 

    \glspl{wn}\\
    count: \glsentrycurrcount{wn}

    \section{C}
    \Glspl{wn}\\
    \gls{wn}\\
    count: \glsentrycurrcount{wn}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I however, would have expected/wanted a count of 4 in section A, and in section C, that at first the full description is printed instead of `WNs`

How to make this work reliably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was given by Nicola [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98494/glossaries-dont-print-single-occurences/230664?noredirect=1#comment1207805_230664) in this [example](http://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/samples/sample-entrycount.tex):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting
 {abbreviation}% list of categories to use entry counting
 {2}% trigger value

\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}
\newabbreviation{xml}{XML}{extensible markup language}
\newabbreviation{css}{CSS}{cascading style sheet}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={sample}}

\begin{document}
This is a sample document that uses entry counting. The entry counting
has been enabled on the \texttt{abbreviation} category.
This means that abbreviations will only be added to the glossary 
if they have been used more than $n$ times, where in this 
document $n$ has been set to
\glsgetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{entrycount}.
Entries in other categories behave as normal.


Used once: \gls{html}.

Used twice: \gls{xml} and \gls{xml}.

Used three times: \gls{css} and \gls{css} and \gls{css}.

Used once but this entry is in the ``general'' category
which doesn't have the ``entrycount'' attribute set:
\gls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

To automatically reset the count e.g. for chapters use this code (copied from manual). Note the `\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting` command.

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}  
\GlsXtrEnableEntryUnitCounting{abbreviation}{2}{chapter}  
\makeglossaries  
\newabbreviation{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}  
\newabbreviation{css}{CSS}{cascading style sheet}  
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={sample}}  
\begin{document}  
\chapter{Sample}  
Used once: \gls{html}.  
Used three times: \gls{css} and \gls{css} and \gls{css}.  
Used once: \gls{sample}.  
\chapter{Another Sample}  
Used once: \gls{css}.  
Used twice: \gls{html} and \gls{html}.  
\printglossaries  
\end{document}
```

I am just pasting this here for the sake of completeness, please upvote the answer the in the other thread.

Comment: How does this take care of the "more than once *within section/chapter/part*"-bit of your question? It seems to work when I compile it, but which part of the code defines within which strucutre the counting should be?

Comment: Oh, I see, it's the `\GlsXtrEnableEntryCounting{abbreviation}{2}`

Answer (score 0):

You could make acronyms section-specific by giving them section-specific names. Of course you could easily automate this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[xindy,style=long,numberline,savewrites=true,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeglossaries
\glsenableentrycount 

%create a separate acrony for each section
\let\oldnewacronym\newacronym   \renewcommand{\newacronym}[3]{\foreach \n in {0,...,10}{\oldnewacronym{c\n-#1}{#2}{#3}}}

%%patch all the commands to use the within-section version of the acronym
\let\oldcgls\cgls \renewcommand{\cgls}[1]{\oldcgls{s\arabic{section}-#1}}
\let\oldcglspl\cglspl \renewcommand{\cglspl}[1]{\oldcglspl{s\arabic{section}-#1}}
\let\oldcGlspl\cGlspl \renewcommand{\cGlspl}[1]{\oldcGlspl{s\arabic{section}-#1}}

\newacronym{wn}{WN}{wireless network}

\begin{document}
        \section{A}
        \cgls{wn}\\
        \cglspl{wn}\\
        \cglspl{wn}\\
        \cglspl{wn}\\
        count: \glsentrycurrcount{s1-wn}\\

        \section{B} 
        \cglspl{wn}\\
        count: \glsentrycurrcount{s2-wn}

        \section{C}
        \cGlspl{wn}\\
        \cgls{wn}\\
        count: \glsentrycurrcount{s3-wn}            
\end{document}
```

Basically, when the acronym `wn` is defined, it creates separate acronyms for each section, naming them `s1-wn` and so on. Now when the acronym is called within section X, it  "redirects" and uses `sX-wn`. The result:

[image]

Of course this would need some more tweaking:

1. So far it only works for sections, not chapters, but that should be straighforward
2. It is hard-wired to work for up to 10 sections. You could increase that number, introduce a new counter, or do some .aux-file-magic to automatize this to work for any number of chapters/section/subsections
3. It also needs some further tweaking to deal with symbols and so on.
4. I haven't tried it with `glossaries-extra` so far, because I don't have that installed.
5. I don't now how you want your list of abbreviations to appear. So for now my proposal ignores this, as did your question.

Credits: Part of my solution is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98494/glossaries-dont-print-single-occurences/230664#230664)